# Interfacing LIRC with Haskell

Tags: haskell, ffi, remote-control, client-library

I've been using [pyLirc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pylirc/) while prototyping a small application in Python. For performance reasons (among others) I'm moving to Haskell, but can't find any modules providing similar functionality. Should I just stick with "lirc_client.h" or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no Haskell binding to Lirc yet. It doesn't look too hard.